# Create a 64-bit result using different values

Tags: c

I have to create a 64byte value using `val1`, `val2`, `val3` and `val4`.
Output should look like: `0xabcdabcd01000000`, but I am getting `0x81000000`

```
uint32_t val1 = 0xabcdabcd;
uint8_t val2 = 1;
uint8_t val3 = 0;
uint16_t val4 = 0;
uint8_t final_val[8];
#define ADDR (&final_val[0])
//The output format is as follows: NNNNNNNNxyz
// NNNNNNNN: value1  in hex 
// x - val2, 
// y - val3, 
// z - val4  
int main() {

   uint64_t *ptr = (uint64_t *)ADDR ;
   *ptr = val1<<31|val2<<24|val3<<16|val4;
   printf("%p  0x%x \n", ptr, *ptr);
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Where is `final_val` declared? please provide the minimum code to reproduce

Comment: I think you refer to 64 bit value instead of 64 bytes.

Comment: Does casting val1/2/3/4 to uint64_t  before shifting do the trick?

Comment: You've got a strict-aliasing violation when you dereference a pointer to `final_val[0]` as a `uint64_t`.

Comment: left-shifting a 32-bit int produces a 32-bit result

Comment: And should `val1` be shifted 32 instead of 31?

Comment: `uint64_t *ptr =...    printf("%p  0x%x \n",ptr,*ptr);` implies your compiler is not helping you with good warnings.  Enable all warnings or get a new compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the shift terms except the first is evaluated as an `int`; the first is evaluated as a `uint32_t` which is probably an `unsigned int`.  These results are then or'd together in a `uint32_t`, and then assigned to your 64-bit result.

You need at least the first shift performed as a 64-bit calculation:

```
*ptr = (uint64_t)val1 << 32 | val2 << 24 | val3 << 16 | val4;
```

This can shift by 32 (as required, instead of 31 as before) because the shift is smaller than the size of the operand (`uint64_t`).  Previously, you couldn't use 32 because you'd be told the shift is too big.

You might prefer the symmetry of:

```
*ptr = (uint64_t)val1 << 32 | (uint64_t)val2 << 24 | (uint64_t)val3 << 16 | (uint64_t)val4;
```

Your printing is also faulty.  You should be using the macros from `<inttypes.h>` to specify the format for the `uint64_t` value:

```
printf("%p  0x%" PRIx64 "\n", ptr, *ptr);
```

Note that if you used `unsigned long long *ptr` etc, you'd use `0x%llx`.

The use of `final_val` is also dubious at best; it could crash on some machine types if `final_val` is not appropriately aligned for a 64-bit type (not aligned on a 64-bit boundary).  In the code shown, you should simply use a `uint64_t` variable to be the target of the pointer (since the code shown doesn't use `final_val` otherwise).  If you did need to use the array of `uint8_t` values for some reason, then there are better ways to load the data.  You'd get different results on little-endian vs big-endian machines, too.

Comment: For a complete answer, please add a note that `uint64_t *ptr = (uint64_t *)ADDR ;` is a strict aliasing violation and UB, or alternatively just drop `ptr` in favour for an `uint64_t`. And we really shouldn't shift on `int` or other signed types, ever. So the version with explicit casts on all operands is always to prefer.

Answer (score 4):

To create a 64-bit value:

1) Insure shifts are done with 64-bit operands when the result exceeds 32 bits.

```
val1<<31    
(uint64_t) val1 << 31
```

2) Shift 32, not 31 bits to achieve the goal of NNNNNNNNxyz

3) Avoid pointers tricks.

```
uint8_t final_val[8];
// uint64_t *ptr = (uint64_t *)ADDR ;
uint64_t u64 = (uint64_t) val1 << 32 | val2 << 24 | val3 <<16 | val4;
memcpy(final_val, &u64, sizeof final_val);
```

4) Use matching printf specifiers.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
//            v---- Not x, x is for unsigned
// printf("0x%x\n", u64);
printf("0x%" PRIx64 "\n", u64);
//           ^----^ from inttypes.h
```